# How can I use Ant to build a single executable .jar that has dependency .jars in it in a /lib dir in the .jar?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ant, executable-jar

How can I use Ant to build a single executable *.jar* that has dependency .jars in it in a `/lib` dir in the .*jar*?

I have a `/lib` directory in the project root file that contains all the binary dependency *.jar*s.

Comment: Why don't you use Maven or gradle instead of ant？

Comment: Ok, sure, how would this be done with Maven? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In java an executable jar has a specially formatted [manifest](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html), that includes the following attributes:

1. Main-Class
2. Class-Path

In ANT this is easily accomplished as follows with the [jar](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) task:

```
<jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}" includes="*.class">
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}" />
        <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${jar-classpath}" />
    </manifest>
</jar>
```

For extra credit one can use the very useful [manifestclasspath](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/manifestclasspath.html) task to help assemble the correct classpath string.

```
<manifestclasspath property="jar-classpath" jarfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar">
    <classpath>
        <fileset dir="/path/to/lib/dir" includes="*.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</manifestclasspath>
```